# Discord Bot - Python 3 - passing user variables to other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a dice roller Discord bot qith Python 3. The die number looks up a phrase in a dictionary and the outputs it. I had it fine working with a six sided die, but I want the user to be able to make it a 10 sided die instead.

To roll a die it is '!y1' to set it to 10 sided die it's '!y d10'. I tied setting it to d6 by default, however when I try rolling now it gives me an error of the variable being undefined. Could someone help point me to what I am missing?

```
import os
from random import randint

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

def ybna6_faces(x):
    return{
        1: 'Yes, And...',
        2: 'Yes...',
        3: 'Yes, But...',
        4: 'No, But...',
        5: 'No...',
        6: 'No, And...'
        }[x]

def danger6_faces(x):
        return{
                1: 'Blank',
                2: 'Blank',
                3: 'Blank',
                4: 'Blank',
                5: 'Skull!',
                6: 'Two Skull!!'
                }[x]

def ybna10_faces(x):
    return{
        1: 'Yes, And...',
        2: 'Yes...',
        3: 'Yes, But...',
        4: 'No, But...',
        5: 'No...',
        6: 'No, And...',
        7: '',
        8: '',
        9: '',
        10: ''
        }[x]

def danger10_faces(x):
        return{
                1: 'Blank',
                2: 'Blank',
                3: 'Blank',
                4: 'Blank',
                5: 'Skull!',
                6: 'Two Skull!!',
                7: '',
                8: '',
                9: '',
                10: ''
                }[x]


sides = 6
#active_ybna = 6
#active_danger = 6

w=""

#Successful server connection message
@client.event
async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

#Makes sure bot doesn't respond to itself
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
                return

#Choose die (6 or 10)
        if message.content.startswith('!y d6'):
            sides = 6

        if message.content.startswith('!y d10'):
            sides = 10

#Evaluate rolls
        if message.content.startswith('!y'):
                if int(message.content[2])>int(0):
                        z = int(message.content[2])
                        for x in range(z):   
                                y = randint(1,int(sides))
                                active_ybna = 'ybna'+ sides + '_faces()'
                                response = 'Roll ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + active_ybna(y)
                                await message.channel.send(response)
                if len(message.content)>=4:
                    if int(message.content[4])>int(0):
                        z = int(message.content[4])
                        for x in range(z):
                            y=randint(1,int(sides))
                            active_danger = 'danger'+ sides + '_faces()'
                            response = 'Danger ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + active_danger(y)
                            await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

EDIT:
Traceback on input of '!y1'

```
YBNA Bot has connected to Discord!
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/discord bots/ybnabot.py", line 92, in on_message
    y = randint(1,int(sides))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sides' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the traceback/error?

Comment: I knew I forgot something.... post edited with traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `if` statements that can both evaluate to `False`, meaning it is possible the `sides` variable is never created.

This is because the `sides` you create is outside the function, making it out of scope. You need to move this inside the function or declare `sides` as global (not advised).

```
...

#active_ybna = 6
#active_danger = 6

w=""

#Successful server connection message
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

#Makes sure bot doesn't respond to itself
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    sides = 6
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    #Choose die (6 or 10)
    if message.content.startswith('!y d6'):
        sides = 6

    if message.content.startswith('!y d10'):
        sides = 10

    #Evaluate rolls
    if message.content.startswith('!y'):
        if int(message.content[2])>int(0):
            z = int(message.content[2])
            for x in range(z):   
                 y = randint(1,int(sides))
                 active_ybna = 'ybna'+ sides + '_faces()'
                 response = 'Roll ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + active_ybna(y)
                 await message.channel.send(response)
         if len(message.content)>=4:
             if int(message.content[4])>int(0):
                 z = int(message.content[4])
                 for x in range(z):
                     y=randint(1,int(sides))
                     active_danger = 'danger'+ sides + '_faces()'
                     response = 'Danger ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + active_danger(y)
                     await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my issued was variables not declared Global. I kinda simplified it all and tucked it into one event with multiple IF's.

Some other code added as well...

```
# ybnabot.py
#d6 functionality

import os
from random import randint

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

def ybna6_faces(x):
    return{
        1: 'No, And...',
        2: 'No...',
        3: 'No, But...',
        4: 'Yes, But...',
        5: 'Yes...',
        6: 'Yes, And...'
        }[x]

def danger6_faces(x):
        return{
        1: 'Blank',
        2: 'Blank',
        3: 'Blank',
        4: 'Blank',
        5: ':skull:',
        6: ':skull: :skull:'
        }[x]

def ybna10_faces(x):
    return{
        1: 'No, And...',
        2: 'No, And, But...',
        3: 'No...',
        4: 'Not, But...',
        5: 'No, But, And...',
        6: 'Yes, But, And...',
        7: 'Yes, But...',
        8: 'Yes...',
        9: 'Yes, And, But...',
        10: 'Yes, And...'
        }[x]

def danger10_faces(x):
        return{
                1: 'Blank',
                2: 'Blank',
                3: 'Blank',
                4: 'Blank',
                5: ':skull',
                6: ':skull: :skull',
                7: 'Blank',
                8: 'Blank',
                9: ':skull:',
                10: ':skull: :skull:'
                }[x]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global sides
    sides = 6
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global sides
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

#Send Help DM
    if message.content.startswith('!y help'):
        await message.author.send('YBNA Bot Help!')
        await message.author.send('Commands:')
        await message.author.send('!y X Z - Roll X number of YBNA dice and Z Danger dice (Danger die can be omitted)')
        await message.author.send('!y d6 - Choose six sided dice')
        await message.author.send('!y d10 - Choose 10 sided dice')
        await message.author.send('!y dice - Displays which dice are selected (d6 or d10)')
        await message.author.send('!y help - This message!')
        await message.author.send('txutfz73 credits here')
        await message.author.send('github link here')
        return


#Check die used
    if message.content.startswith('!y dice'):
        response = 'Using ' + str(sides) + ' sided dice!'
        await message.channel.send(response)
        return

#Choose d6 or d10
    if message.content.startswith('!y d6'):
        sides = 6
        await message.channel.send('Now using d6!')
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!y d10'):
        sides = 10
        response = 'Now using d10!'
        await message.channel.send(response)
        return




#Roll d6
    if sides == 6:
        if message.content.startswith('!y'):
            if int(message.content[2])>int(0):
                z = int(message.content[2])
                for x in range(z):
                    y = randint(1,6)
                    response = 'Roll ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + ybna6_faces(y) + str(sides)
                    await message.channel.send(response)

        if len(message.content)>=4:
            if int(message.content[4])>int(0):
                z = int(message.content[4])
                for x in range(z):
                    y=randint(1,6)
                    response = 'Danger ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + danger6_faces(y)
                    await message.channel.send(response)

#Roll d10
    else:
        if message.content.startswith('!y'):
            if int(message.content[2])>int(0):
                z = int(message.content[2])
                for x in range(z):
                    y = randint(1,10)
                    response = 'Roll ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + ybna10_faces(y) + str(sides)
                    await message.channel.send(response)

        if len(message.content)>=4:
            if int(message.content[4])>int(0):
                z = int(message.content[4])
                for x in range(z):
                    y=randint(1,10)
                    response = 'Danger ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + danger10_faces(y)
                    await message.channel.send(response)


client.run(TOKEN)
```